# Selenium C#: Find element of text of URL with extra '/'

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, url, text, assert

Newbie here with Selenium C# and teaching myself along the way.  I have got code and tests running for when I am able to verify a piece of text connected to the URL. Example of what I have got working:
**Code**

```
IWebElement events = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[href='/events']"))
        Assert.That(events.Text, Is.EqualTo("Events"));
```

**HTML**

[image: HTML001]

However, I am trying to access the following text within another drop down menu which has extra '/' at the end of each URL and assert its text is true:

I get the following that the String is empty.
**Error**:

```
  Message: 
  Expected string length 22 but was 0. Strings differ at index 0.
  Expected: "Português (Brasileiro)"
  But was:  <string.Empty>
  -----------^
```

**Code**

```
 IWebElement portuguêse = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[href='/pt-br/']"));
      Assert.That(portuguêse.Text, Is.EqualTo("Português (Brasileiro)"));
```

**HTML**

[image: HTML002]

I have identified the only difference between the code that is able to be selected is the extra '/' at the end of the URL in /pt-br/ which is not in the URL /events.

If someone could guide me on the correct way of selecting the element for text which has no span class that would be great!

Thanks!

Kirsty

Comment: The fact that there's a slash at the end of the `href` attribute is a coincidental difference. That's not going to arbitrarily affect the *text* content. It's much more likely that your selector is matching an element that appears in the DOM before the one you want. Verify that you're getting the right element before testing that it has the right text.

Comment: Could you provide me with some solutions to use for this checking the right element?

Comment: Marker attributes for one.  Put an attribute on it that can't possibly exist on another element and check that the marker is there. A more specific selector, for another. Select it by a path that shouldn't match for any other element that might have otherwise matched... something like `ul[class='dropdown-menu'] li a[class='dropdown-item'][href='/pt-br/']` based on what you've shown. It will depend on the whole and actual structure of the HTML document to know what should be specific enough. This is where creativity can play a part in writing tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid this try `startswith` using `css selector` to identify the element.

```
IWebElement portuguêse = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[href^='/pt-br']"));
Assert.That(portuguêse.getAttribute("textContent"), Is.EqualTo("Português (Brasileiro)"));
```

OR

Use this `starts-with` and `ends-with`

```
IWebElement portuguêse = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[href^='/pt-br'][href$='pt-br/']"));
Assert.That(portuguêse.getAttribute("textContent"), Is.EqualTo("Português (Brasileiro)"));
```

Comment: No luck with either still getting 
  Message: 
  Expected string length 22 but was 0. Strings differ at index 0.
  Expected: "Português (Brasileiro)"
  But was:  <string.Empty>
  -----------^

Comment: @KirstyMeredith, It seems it is hidden, Instead of `Text`, Please use  `getAttribute("textContent")`

Comment: Brilliant KunduK!!! It worked!!  Thank you soo much, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
IWebElement events = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("a.dropdown-item"))
    Assert.That(events.Text, Is.EqualTo("Events"));
```

Please change the **CssSelector** value to **a.dropdown-item**

Comment: Nilekesh the Events assert is working ok and I do not want to change it.  It is the IWebElement portuguêse = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[href='/pt-br/']"));
      Assert.That(portuguêse.Text, Is.EqualTo("Português (Brasileiro)"));  That is not working and that I want to change